# Python reading from serial

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to read data from an RFID (RMD6300) to Raspberry Pi 1 in python but after reading for 30-40 secs whitout interruptions it crashes with the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tmp.py", line 7, in
>   
>       string = ser.read(20)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line
>   501, in read
>       'device reports readiness to read but returned no data ' serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read
>   but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

this is my code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600, timeout=1)
IDs = ["xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx"]
while True:
    bool = False;
    string = ser.read(20)
    if len(string) == 0:
        print "Insert tag"
        continue
    else:
        for i in range(len(IDs)):
            for l in range(len(string)):
                if IDs[i] in string:
                    print IDs[i]
                    bool = True
                    break
                 else:
                     string = string[1:]+string[0]
             if bool:
                 break
    if not bool:
        print "Not found"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: ... device reports readiness to read but returned no data

Increase your `timeout`:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600, timeout=1)
```

Use `try ... except`

```
try:
    string = ser.read(20)
except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
    except_counter +=1
    if except_counter == 5:
       break

    time.sleep(1)
```

> **Question**: ...device disconnected or multiple access on port?

Can you exclude this two points?